How do I add a network to the list of Safe{Core} Supported Networks?
Is it possible to have a network officially supported (i.e., added here: https://docs.safe.global/core-api/transaction-service-supported-networks)?

I'm not sure if they have different levels of network support, but the best network support includes stuff like running off-chain infrastructure. That's used at least for signature propagation so only the last approval of a tx needs an on-chain transaction.
So getting a network added officially is a lot more work than adding it into a list. And running that infra is not trivial. Probably they have some form or way of requesting a new network - don't really know how it works.

There is a comprehensive guide to add official support to a given network. You will need to deploy the Safe contracts on your network, then open a PR to the safe-deployment repository, and finally run your infrastructure for supporting this network. As Lauri wrote, it is indeed a lot of work, and Safe indeed offers different levels of support. The best way would be to follow the guide entirely though.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
